# pow(); function causing inconsistent results

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

This is the code:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int findIntLen(int num); // A function that finds the amount of digits an integer has.

int main(void)
{
    int num = 0, temp = 0, res = 0;
    int index = 0, digit = 0;

    // Receive a number to be flipped from the user.
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer to be flipped: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        getchar();
    } while (num < 1);

    temp = num;              // Assign the number value to a temporary variable so we do not lose our original value.
    index = findIntLen(num); // Generate an index variable that will be modified on each iteration.
    while (index > 0)
    {
        digit = temp % 10;                 // Find the next digit.
        res += digit * pow(10, index - 1); // Add the correct value to the result variable.
        temp = temp / 10;                  // Divide the temporary variable by 10 so we check the next digit on the next iteration.
        index--;                           // Subtract 1 from the index to multiply by correct power of 10 on next iteration.
    }
    /*  Example of the idea:
        if number is 15:
        digit count would be 2 therefor initial index would be 1.
        res += 5 * pow(10, 1) => 5 * 10 = 50

        * Next Iteration *
        Index is now 0:
        res += 1 * pow(10, 0) => 1 * 1 = 1

        FINAL RESULT: 51
    */

    printf("Flipped %d = %d\n", num, res); // Print final result.

    return 0;
}

int findIntLen(int num)
{
    int len = 0;

    while (num != 0)
    {
        num /= 10;
        len++;
    }

    return len;
}
```

**When I run it using Visual Studio it works fine, but when i compile it with gcc the final digit seems to get subtracted by 1.**

[image: A non working example in using gcc]

[image: A working example in visual studio]

**The program is intended to receive an integer and flip it, then print the new integer, like so:**

[image: Correct run of the program]

If anyone knows what the origin of this problem may be I would love to know.
I am using `Visual Studio 2019`, gcc version `gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0` and all running on a `Windows 10` pc.

Comment: `scanf("%ld", &num);` is incorrect, should be `scanf("%d", &num);` On one compiler `long` is the same size as `int` (so it happened to work), but not on the other. I suggest you increase the compiler warning level to catch such things.

Comment: oops i accidentally shared a failed attempt of fixing this code, it didn't work the first time with regular `%d` so i thought it might be an overflow of some sort but it still didn't work, i will change the code. **The `%ld` was not the problem!**

Comment: There is a possible problem from the use of `pow()` with integers, which can suffer from the inexactness of floating point. Try `res += digit * (int)round(pow(10, index - 1));` but better not to use `pow()` for this sort of thing if possible.

Comment: @WeatherVane holy cow that was actually it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works on my own gcc (`gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)`).

However, some of your numbers are integers, some are *long integers*. On platforms where these two are the same thing, it doesn't make difference. On platforms where, say, ints are 16 bits and longs are 32, or 32 and 64, then you might get undefine behaviour.

Then if I might suggest a different approach, you can use the number itself as index; and you needn't use `pow()` (this is an adaptation of Horner's algorithm).

```
for (res = 0; temp; temp/=10) {
    res = res*10 + temp % 10;
}
```

The only explanation I can wrack out of my head is that the division by 10 somehow accumulates an error. Not really possible as is, since the error should appear in the rightmost digits first, but either that or I have to believe in magick, which I don't.

Try to catch the gremlin red-handed by printing the intermediate values (this is the alternative approach, the division is the same, but you can easily instrument the original code):

```
printf("Let us start. Temp=%d\n", temp);
for (res = 0; temp; temp/=10) {
    printf("Iteration...\n");
    printf("  temp is now %d, last digit is %d\n", temp, temp % 10);
    res = res*10 + temp % 10;
    printf("  so, res is now %d\n", res);
}
printf("Finished.\n");
```

## update

In the end I did not wait, and got me a MinGW-GCC.

First thing: **Your GCC is old**. I have 9.2.0, you seem to have installed 6.3.0.

Second thing, and also the bug explained at last: **POW being float, it suffers from errors** (I should have noticed that first). To save time I just put a simple diagnostic printout in the loop. It should list powers of ten by seven -- and it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: OP says that was a typo :(

Comment: The long and regular integers were an example of the non original code, i edited the code so it will be correct this time, again, the long integers were not the problem! I will try to change my gcc version but it seems weird to me that this would not work...

Comment: Liked the different approach btw

Comment: @RazKissos I have no explanation; I tried your code (both %d and %ld) and it worked. I tested it with 777 too, just in case.

Comment: @LSerni what gcc version do you have?

Comment: @RazKissos I wrote that on top first thing ;-) -- I'm sorry, I don't have a gcc available for Windows 10 just now. I'm so intrigued by this that tomorrow I'll surely try to get me one, though.

Comment: @LSerni thanks a lot! glad to see someone as intrigued as I am.

Comment: BTW @LSerni do you have any idea of how to update my gcc compiler to a newer version? i have searched online but i only found my version as the newest for windows...

Comment: @RazKissos don't know. I got mine from mingw.org, and it came with an installer (mingw-get). I guess you could backup your old directory, then install mingw from scratch in another, and finally move the files and check whether it works (if it doesn't, you can still restore the backup). I use this method with several utilities.

Answer (score 1):

As @WeatherVane suggested: There is a possible problem from the use of pow() with integers, which can suffer from the inexactness of floating point. Try `res += digit * (int)round(pow(10, index - 1));` but better not to use pow() for this sort of thing if possible.

My final code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 0, temp = 0, res = 0;
    int index = 0, digit = 0;

    // Receive a number to be flipped from the user.
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer to be flipped: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        getchar();
    } while (num < 1);

    // Generate the result:
    for (res = 0, temp = num; temp != 0; temp /= 10)
        res = res * 10 + temp % 10;

    printf("Flipped %d = %d\n", num, res); // Print final result.

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot to @LSerni and @WeatherVane!!!

Comment: LOL, I had just come up with that a few minutes ago :-D (I was *too* intrigued to wait for the morning)